# How to Fix the Failing Notification-Bar in CM13?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, data-transfer, usability

The notification-bar fails in my new official CM13 installation

[image]

I have not removed *CyonogenSetupWizard*, which can cause such an event. 
The device show no notifications at all. 
I need to find in settings how to enable the data transfer from the phone to my computer.

### Final solution

Reflashing unstable ROM with unstable ROM is not a good idea. 
I switched off from kyasu's ROM and official ROM (noise artifact).
I then switched to Temasek/arter97's ROM found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4/i9506-develop/rom-temasek-s-unofficial-cyanogenmod-12-t3082164) because of its mature development, thorough documentation and solves the noise artifact bug in the official ROM. Smooth installation also.

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S4 gt-i9506
ROMs used: official ROM, *cm_ks01lte-userdebug 6.0.1 MOB30D 56236a0be1*, Temasek's unofficial ROM where I did not manage to reproduce the problem in Temasek's ROM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem a couple days ago. I felt like the only way to fix it is reinstalling cm. But I fortunately managed to make the notification bar work again. I was looking for some solution in the phone's settings, and when I went to "Users" I accidently switched to guest mode and back. Then my phone got frozen for a few mintues, then it locked itself and finaly the notifications appeared on the lock screen. Then I restarted  my phone and since then everything's just fine. I hope if someone else still has this problem I could help him/her.

cm-13.0-20160418-SNAPSHOT-ZNH0EAO2NJ-serranoltexx

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings menu, about phone, down to build number, tap 7-8 times. Go back to developer options in the settings menu and down until you see device usb configuration and select mtp then you should be able to transfer between the devices.

Comment: My build number is cm_ks01lte-userdebug 6.0.1 MOB30D 56236a0be1 test-keys.

Comment: Yeah tap on that until you have unlocked developer options

Comment: I enabled it but I do not detect it on my Mac. I know that it should be detected. I have used many phones. Something is wrong in the system. How to debug here?

Comment: This happened with my S6 the only thing that worked was reflash CM

Answer (score 1):

An answered question but I'd still like to weigh in. The only case I've seen where notification bar won't work (i.e. no notifications) is when you removed SetupWizard (in CM's case, CyanogenSetupWizard) after flashing. This will also lead to some nav keys unusable and a myriad of other weird bugs. Just put it back in, set the proper permissions, reboot, walk through the setup and things should be back to normal.

Honestly I don't know why CM made CyanogenSetupWizard compulsory since late April - things had been working without it before, now we have to walk through a wizard which does nothing useful.

Comment: Since the discussion clearly shows we're not talking on the same channel, I'll leave you alone with your own solution. Next time tell people to flash other ROMs when all they want is to solve a problem on their existing ROM.